# Not able to show a View Controller as pop up controller in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to add my view controller as pop up controller. But everyt ime i use the code the view comes sliding from bottom and not as i wish. Below is the code i'm using

```
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let popupVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WSFilterViewController") as! WSFilterViewController
    popupVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle .popover
    popupVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize (width: 300, height:300)
    let pVC = popupVC.popoverPresentationController
    pVC?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.any
    pVC?.delegate = self as? UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate
    self.present(popupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I want it as in the image shown

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: as docs says: In a horizontally compact environment, this option behaves the same as fullScreen.

Comment: you are on iPad or iPhone device?

Comment: you are missing source view , sourceRect , and Delegate

Answer (score 2):

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let popupVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WSFilterViewController")
    popupVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle .popover
    popupVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 170, height: 130)
    popupVC.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    popupVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as? UIView // button
    popupVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = (sender as AnyObject).bounds
    self.present(popupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The issue was something different and figured it out now.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

```
 func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle
{
    return .none
}
```

you must add the code above on iPhone devices, otherwise it will keep showing full screen.